# How to fix grainy recoding with ffmpeg mp4 x264?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, http-live-streaming, libx264

I recorded the audio and video stream from a streaming with ffmpeg. when I go to re-encode the file using libx264, the video in the movements looks bad and grainy as in the image.
Where did I go wrong?

[image: Sample]

this is the code I used

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac output.mp4
```

and these are mediainfo of original file

```
    Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isom
    creation_time   : 2020-03-19T22:43:32.000000Z
  Duration: 00:39:51.99, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1300 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x1080 [SAR 3:2 DAR 16:9], Closed Captions, 1268 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(spa): Audio: aac (HE-AACv2) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 22 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

mediainfo of the file recoded

```
 Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:39:51.99, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 7924 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], Closed Captions, 7892 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 119.88 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(spa): Audio: aac (HE-AACv2) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 22 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

How can I recode the file without loss of quality? (sorry for my poor english)

Comment: The problem here has to do with interlacing and scaling.  I assume somewhere in the chain that video is interlaced?

Comment: I think so. the file has a size of 1280x1080 and I do the recoding to make the file from 1920x1080. How can I fix it?

Comment: Add a deinterlacing filter.  https://video.stackexchange.com/a/17397/129  You might have to get a bit creative to ensure the deinterlacing occurs before the scaling.

Comment: I have tried and it works great! the only problem is that deinterlacing does not work with the scaling in the same encoding.
I have to redo the encoding for a second time just to change the scaling of video .. (and lose many more hours) is it not possible to do both once? sorry but I'm not an expert

Comment: i tried this `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf yadif=1,scale=1920:1080 -c:v libx264 -crf 19 -c:a aac -r 30 output.mp4` and it works .. the only thing is that the file has a large size (1 minute of encoding I am already 65mb. if you have a way to make it lighter I would be grateful (and then I finish .. sorry)

Comment: You can use `-b:v` to set the video bitrate, but that isn't really a large file.  Video takes a lot of bandwidth, especially at 1920x1080.  Why not just leave it as the original file?  It doesn't look like you're really converting anything.